# typedef an overloaded function

Tags: c++, overloading, typedef

you can typedef a data type:

```
typedef String std::string;
```

You can typedef a function

```
typedef String itos(int val);
itos std::to_string;
```

How can you typedef an overloaded function

eg.

```
typedef String to_string(all overloads);
to_string std::to_string;
```

Comment: You can't. The types of the parameters to a function are part of the type, if you have different parameters you have a different type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ overload mechanism allows to call functions with the same name but different argument types. Each overloaded function has different type (really they all are separate functions). For each such function compiler generates [decorated names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) of the functions, adding parameter types to the function name, so that linker can distinguish them.

[typedef](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) does not create separate type. So, you cannot match several types to one typedef declaration, it is impossible. In C++11 you can use [using](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) type aliasing instead of typedef which has more clear syntax.